# Title and price on the same row

Tags: html, css

have title, price and unit in gram in div element.
I'd like price be always on right corner next to first row of title (see example), can't get it, always goes after the title.

[image]

```
<div class="info-block">
   <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-top: 18px; margin-left: 10px;"><span class="title"><?=$last['title']?></span></p>
   <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 10px; float:right;"><span class="price"><?=$last['price']?></span> тг.</p>

        </div>
```

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: You've placed it after the title. Why should it appear before the title?

Comment: If you use <p> tag you can't place price in same line, it will go to next line.

Comment: I put code but it doesn't work so don't know how to do it

Comment: @Wais Kamal: do you have any idea how to get it? Thanks

Comment: Use `<span>` instead of `<p>`

Comment: @Wais Kamal: put span but it still doesn't put price to first row put at the end of title.

Comment: Can you please post your CSS? It is impossible to tell how your code was structured by just looking at the image.

Comment: Image is just example what I want, and the code I put is what I tried so far and it doesn't work

Comment: actually I put all the style in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to be working:

```
.left{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 70%
 }

 .right{
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
   width: 30%
 }

  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='left'>This should be on the leftggdfgfdgdfgdfgfd fgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdgdgdfgdfgdfgdfdfdfgdfgdfgfgdfggdgsdsdfgsdgsdfgdsssgsd</div>
    <div class='right'>And this should be on the right </div>
 </div>
```